# sub-queries are running fast but joining them is taking forever

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables (sample below) with some additional columns that I have not shown here. The only way to join the two tables is by using a combination of first name, last name, and address.

table A (~3000 rows):

| First Name | Last Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 123 Main St |
| Jack | Jones | 100 Chestnut St |
| Tom | Locke | 50 Market St |

table B (~ 9M rows):

| First Name | Last Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 123 Main St |
| Jack | Jones | 100 Chestnut St |
| Jeremy | Thomas | 27 Spruce St |

I have tried the following code -

```sql
select * from 
(select first_name, last_name, address, concat(first_name, last_name, address) as con_A
from table_A) as A
join
(select first_name, last_name, address, concat(first_name, last_name, address) as con_B
from table_B) as B
on A.con_A=B.con_B
```

The above code is a generalization of what my code looks like. I have tried to only put the columns I need in the sub queries in my original code.

The two sub queries run within seconds when I run them individually but taking over an hour to execute when I join them.

Comment: Why use subqueries at all? Why not just join table A to table B On firstname,  lastname, address?

Comment: Have you tried the posted answers below?  If the direct table joins don't give you the desired results, then we need to better understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that I'd use inline tables for this ... why not just a direct join?

```
select
    A.first_name,
    A.last_name,
    A.address
from
    table_A A
    join table_B B on A.first_name = B.first_name AND
    A.last_name = B.last_name AND
    A.address = B.address
```

Now this is an inner join, so you'll only get exact matches for both.  If you want to show records from one table whether they match or not, you'll need to use an outer join (left or right depending on the table you want to drive the results).

Comment: I'll also add, if the data between your tables has subtle differences due to leading / trailing spaces, and you want to ignore case, you'll need to wrap the comparisons with expressions TRIM(UPPER()) on both sides of the equation.  This will impact your query performance because you won't be able to utilize pruning - this is because each side of the where clause comparisons use the results of the expression ... meaning all values have to be processed prior to comparison.  If this is prolific, it is better to add columns to these tables and store the processed value to use in execution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the sub query in join you can directly use the join for better performance of the query.

```
select A.first_name, A.last_name, A.address from 
(select first_name, last_name, address from table_A) as A
join
(select first_name, last_name, address from table_B) as B
on A.first_name=B.first_name, A.last_name=B.last_name, A.address=B.address
```

And one more thing don't use normal join use either left or right join based on your need. If you joining 3k records with 9M records all combination will form in the result. It makes very cost effective operation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My query is running faster than before but I am getting a very few rows. 45 to be exact. But that probably has something to do with my code. Thanks a lot.